# Python / Word2Vec: How to project a word on two axis e.g. 'man-woman' and 'rich-poor'

Tags: python, numpy, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

How can I project a word W on an X-axis which represents the scale 'man-woman' and on Y-axis which represents the scale 'poor-rich'?

Let's say my word is:

```
word = model.wv['king']
```

and I would like to project on:

model.wv['rich'] and model.wv['poor'] on my X-Axis
model.wv['man'] and model.wv['woman'] on my Y-Axis

I am using Python / numpy / Word2Vec.

I tried this:

```
b1 = model.wv['man'] - model.wv['woma']
b2 = model.wv['rich'] - model.wv['poor']
B = np.array([b1, b2])
Bi = np.linalg.pinv(B.T)
```

and then:

```
Wv = model.wv['king']
W = np.array(Wv)
Wp = np.matmul(Bi,W.T)
Wp = (Wp.T-[Wp[0,2],Wp[1,0]]).T
```

but for this last line I get:

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

Comment: It's unclear what your code is trying to do. Is it copied from some working example somewhere? And, if you have an error, other can help far more if you supply the entire error – with any lines of 'traceback' showing exactly which lines-of-code are involved, in your code and the libraries it calls – rather than just one tiny excerpt.

Comment: Dear @gojomo, thank you for your answer. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I will try to explain it better.

Well I would like to project a word embedding in a 2D subspace where for example the man-woman line is one of the axes (let's say X) and the rich-poor line is the other (Y).

I tried to adapt what is describe on this web site:
https://towardsdatascience.com/visualisation-of-embedding-relations-word2vec-bert-64d695b7f36

But I have an error on this line:
 Wp = (Wp.T-[Wp[0,2],Wp[1,0]]).T
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

Comment: If you have an error, other can help far more if you supply the entire error – with any lines of 'traceback' showing exactly which lines-of-code are involved, in your code and the libraries it calls – rather than just one tiny excerpt. You can edit your question to add such valuable multi-line information.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you're trying to mimic, at https://towardsdatascience.com/visualisation-of-embedding-relations-word2vec-bert-64d695b7f36, the variable `Wv` is a list of 10 vectors, each of (from other context there) 300 dimensions:

```
Wl = ['man', 'woman', 'rich', 'poor', 'queen',
      'king', 'fisherman', 'teacher', 'actress', 'actor']
Wv = []
for i in range(len(Wl)):
    # Embeddings
    Wv.append(word2vec[Wl[i]])
```

In your code, Wv is just a single vector of an unclear number of dimensions:

```
Wv = model.wv['king']
```

To mimic their results, you will at least want to match the same object/vector "shapes" of that example. At a bare minimum, that would require your Wv to be a list with your single vector in it:

```
Wv = [ model.wv['king'] ]
```

However, I'd suggest you might as well mimic their practice of comparing many vectors, for a similarly-interesting presentation of multiple words. For example, make your `Wv` something like:

```
Wv = [ model.wv[word] for word in ['man', 'woman', 'rich', 'poor', 'queen',
                                   'king', 'fisherman', 'teacher', 'actress', 'actor'] ]
```

Then, it is also a list of vectors for all 10 words.

(Separately, your line setting `b1` uses `'woma'` which looks like a typo for `'woman'`.)